# I need a simple TCP load balancer in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, firewall, port-forwarding, tcp-ip

I would like to create a load balancer for RDP connections only, that’s one TCP port only and would like to avoid anything more complex like Nginx.

I don’t need cache, or anything else, just take an incoming tcp connection and establish an internal connection to one on N servers with less connections. Once the connection is dropped, if restablished, it can be sent to any other server.

I read about a project called Balance from more than 10 years ago but it is gone, so I’m looking for an active project.

Any hints? Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

[pen](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/man1/pen.1.html) it will have and use features you list as not needed but the tool is so easy to use I am going to ignore you on those ;-)

> Pen is a load balancer for udp and tcp based protocols such  as  dns,  http  or  smtp.  It
> allows  several  servers to appear as one to the outside and automatically detects servers
> that are down and distributes  clients  among  the  available  servers.  This  gives  high
> availability and scalable performance.
>
> The  load balancing algorithm keeps track of clients and will try to send them back to the
> server they visited the last time. The client table has a number of slots  (default  2048,
> settable  through command-line arguments). When the table is full, the least recently used
> one will be thrown out to make room for the new one.

```
pen 80 www1:8000:10 www2:80:10 www3
```

> Here  three  servers cooperate in a web server farm. Host www1 runs its web server on port `8000` and accepts a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections.  Host www2 runs on port `80`  and     accepts  10  connections.  Finally,  www3  runs  its  web  server on port `80` and allows an  unlimited number of simultaneous connections.

Oh and "In part inspired by balance by Thomas Obermair.".

Comment: Oh and "it's bull's eye" :-)